# C# MVC Post form not passing ID from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, http-post

I am new to MVC. I work on an auction application. On the auction site, there should be a form for making a bid. I have a problem passing the auction parameter to the controller

My models:

```
public class Auctions
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    (..) some other fields
    public List<Bid> bids = new List<Bid>(); 
}

public class BiddingViewModel
{
    public Auctions auctionToSend { get; set; }
    public double bid { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@model BiddingViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("CreateBid", "Auction", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.auctionToSend)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.bid)
    <input type="submit" value="Make it work" />

}
```

and my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult AuctionPage(int id)
{
    var tmp = _context.Auctions.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == id);

    BiddingViewModel bvm = new BiddingViewModel
    {
        auctionToSend = tmp,
        bid = -1
    };

    return View(bvm);
}


[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateBid(BiddingViewModel bvm)
{
    //After filling the form from view, the bvm.auctionToSend is null, whereas the bvm.bid value is visible
    return RedirectToAction("AuctionList", "Auction");
}
```

My problem is that the auction data (perfectly visible in the view) is not sent back to the controller. I checked the internet and it showed me some naming-conflicts' solutions, so I made sure the naming is different, but this didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auctionToSend` is a complex object and your use of `@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.auctionToSend)` is generating

```
<input type="hidden" name="auctionToSend" value="yourAssembly.Auctions" ... />
```

If you just need the ID of the `Auctions`, then use

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.auctionToSend.ID)
```

otherwise you need to generate a hidden input for each property of `Auctions` but that would be inefficient, particularly as `Auctions` contains a property which is a collection, so if you need the `Auctions` object in the POST method, better to just get it again based on the ID value your submitting.

As a side note, you really should be using a view model with just properties for the `double Bid` and `int AuctionID`

Comment: Hello, Stephen, thanks for your reply. I am a bit confused. I need to pass the Auction from Controller to View (AuctionPage method) so in the View my Model needs to be at least @model Auctions.   Then how to pass only the pair (auction.ID and bid) back to the controller? What arguments should CreateBid function take?

Comment: If you just use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.auctionToSend.ID)`, then `Auction` property of `bvm` will be initialized in the POST method and its ID will be bound (but the other properties of `Auction` will be `null`)

Comment: Yeah! It worked! Thank you very much - just one more question. I think you meant I "shouldn't" be using a view model - so if i wanted to delete my view model from the project and use @model Auctions instead, how would I pass both auction.ID and bid (user input) to the controller?

Comment: No I mean should. Despite the name of your `BiddingViewModel` its not really a view model because a view model should not contain data models, especially when editing (take for example, the case where `Auctions` has a property that had say `[Required]` - because you only posting back the `ID` value then `ModelState` would always be invalid)

Comment: Thanks! Have a nice day! :)